# Make part of the code a separate component of Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm experimenting with Next 13 and routing it through the app directory. Now Next is trying to work mainly on the server, and because of this I have a problem.
I have a blog page that has a feature for uploading articles by clicking on a button. Since this function uses useState, this page needs to be made `"use client"`, but the fact is that the service function `{getAllPosts}` is imported to this page that collects mdx files into an array of articles. This service function cannot be used together with "use client". Next claim that it is normal practice to use `"use client"` in a separate component and import it to a page with server generation. Here is my code:

```
import { useState } from "react"

import Link from 'next/link'

import { getAllPosts } from '@/lib/getAllData'

export default function Blog() {

    /*loadmore*/
    const initialPostList = 2
    const incrementInitialPostList = 1;

    const [showPosts, setShowPosts] = useState(initialPostList);

    const handleLoadMore = () => {
        setShowPosts(showPosts + incrementInitialPostList)
    }

    const blogs = getAllPosts()

    return (
        <main className="flex flex-col">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">
                Мой блог
            </h1>


            <section className='py-10'>

                <div className='py-2'>
                    {blogs.slice(0, showPosts).map(blog => (
                        <Link href={'/blog/' + blog.slug} passHref key={blog.slug}>
                            <div className='py-2 flex justify-between align-middle gap-2'>
                                <div>
                                    <h3 className="text-lg font-bold">{blog.meta.title}</h3>
                                    <p className="text-gray-400">{blog.meta.description}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="my-auto text-gray-400">
                                    <p>{blog.meta.date}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                    ))}

                    {showPosts < blogs.length ? (
                        <div><button className="mainBtn loadBtn" onClick={handleLoadMore}>Больше статей</button></div>
                        ) : (
                        <div><button className="mainBtn loadBtn" disabled>Больше нет статей</button></div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
    )
}
```

The question is, how do I make a part of the above code a separate component? I'm not good at it at all. It is the code that is responsible for downloading articles:

```
/*loadmore*/
    const initialPostList = 2
    const incrementInitialPostList = 1;

    const [showPosts, setShowPosts] = useState(initialPostList);

    const handleLoadMore = () => {
        setShowPosts(showPosts + incrementInitialPostList)
    }


....


{showPosts < blogs.length ? (
                        <div><button className="mainBtn loadBtn" onClick={handleLoadMore}>More posts</button></div>
                        ) : (
                        <div><button className="mainBtn loadBtn" disabled>No posts</button></div>
                    )}
```

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Is It Unsolvable?